# TrueCrypt container in Google Drive

Tags: truecrypt, google-drive

I have a TrueCrypt file container in the Google Drive folder. I add stuff into it, make sure TrueCrypt changed the timestamp of the container. Google Drive syncs with the server, but it seems it transfers the whole file instead of the bit which is changed in the TrueCrypt container.

Would you know how to make it only sync the changed bit of the container instead of 5GB every time?

Comment: A loopback device, such as an encrypted container with a static size, is the wrong solution for this kind of situation.  It works for Dropbox users due to their use of differentials.  But the right solution would be to use an encyrpted filesystem, such as encFS. This was even [suggested](http://www.grc.com/sn/sn-350.htm) by a Google engineer, Tyler McHenry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like Google Drive doesn't have differential uploading at this time. That's unfortunate. You are at the mercy of how they handle uploads. It seems like this kind of a feature is something they will probably eventually want to have.

Comment: Yea I thought Google could read the binary difference in the container, finger cross it will be in next update, thanks anyway!

Comment: Not even Dropbox has this — are you aware of the overhead that this would require?

Comment: rsync does it easy, and has been for a long time. depending on what you're doing, and how much data is involved, it can take some time, but with modern equipment this is a moot point.

Comment: @slhck - Dropbox does indeed only transfer changed data for TrueCrypt volumes. I have been doing that for a couple of years.

Comment: @rlduffy Interesting, didn't know that. Does it do that only for TrueCrypt or other files as well?

Comment: Dropbox does it for all files.

Answer (score 6):

Search true crypt and Dropbox and you will see that this is possible. I do this All the time with Dropbox And works great.  There is a true crypt setting and then Dropbox does a block hash and uploads your 1gb container in seconds.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is not specific to google drive, google drive does use differentiation between plain files.  This is always going to be the situation with encrypted files because the operating system sees is the encrypted container, not the files within (as per the fact that it's encrypted in the first place).  Because the encrypted container will change as a whole every time there is a change rather than just changing partial, it will often be treated as a whole new file.

Comment: Incorrect, the it uses blocks, so you do not see the whole file being changed.